# Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, networking, nftables, netfilter

I'm trying to configure a tap connection on my host os (devuan 4) on my ARM chromebook because I want to use it with qemu and the guest os that I want to virtualize on top of devuan,using qemu+kvm,that's FreeBSD 13.2 for armv7.

Below are the commands that I should issue :

a) set up a tap on the host:

```
# ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap
# ip address add 10.0.2.1/24 dev tap0
```

b) setting up forwarding and NAT (over eth0):

```
# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

At this point I want to use the nftables to reach the goal and I did something like this :

```
# nft add table nat
# nft 'add chain nat postrouting { type nat hook postrouting priority 100 ; }'
```

but I get this error :

```
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
```

Someone gave to me some suggestions to fix it :

> "Your table has no family. You are also trying to add a chain to a
> table called "postrouting" in the "nat" family, which does not exist.
> All of your other rules are part of the "ip" family so this one should
> be too"

Honestly I'm not able to understand what to do,this topic is very out of my competences. So,please can someone help me more ? please be patient...thanks.

Comment: Considering your exact (two) nft commands work here, I would check if the kernel got all the required configuration options to support nftables + nat. About the missing family. It's not missing: when not provided it defaults to `ip` (IPv4). Still you should avoid using a table called `nat` (or `ip nat`) because it could clash with `iptables-nft`'s use of the very same table.